# jQuery get all HTML attributes

Tags: jquery, html

is there a way to get the list of attributes set to an element?

example:

```
<div id="myID" title="I am Title" myAttr="I am something else">Hello World!!!</div>
```

Is there a way to get all the above attributes?

I tried this already but nothing so far:

```
$('#myID').attr();
```

I tried this as well:

```
$('#myID').attr().each(function(a,b){
    alert(a);
});
```

did not help either... so any suggestions would be appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/getAttributes

Comment: i dont really like addons/plugins... it would be my last result... i have already seen that, but thanks

Comment: Then look at the code of the plugin to see how it's done, eh?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the DOM `attributes` property on the underlying jQuery element to extract a `NamedNodeMap` containing all of the element's attributes. This can be quickly parsed into an object which could be passed directly to `.attr()`.

```
var attrs = {};
var attrMap = $('#myID')[0].attributes;
$.each(attrMap, function(i,e) { attrs[e.nodeName] = e.nodeValue; });
```

`attrs` is now:

```
{id: "myID", title: "I am Title", myattr: "I am something else"}
```

Here's a jsfiddle that shows how this works: http://jsfiddle.net/joemaller/cDYtr/

Answer (score 0):

Or this one: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-list-attributes/